# Significado de "I build my own self-worth through the lowest opinions of others”

Tags: traducción, significado-en-contexto

> “This doesn’t mean, incidentally, that I’m always likeable (I’m not) but that I **build my own self-worth** through **the lowest opinions** of others.”

1. "the lowest" como **dañinas**, los comentarios sarcásticos o denigrantes afectaban su autoestima, su autoestima podía estar alta o baja, pero con eso afectaba su valía como persona.
2. "the lowest" como **equivocadas**, es decir, porque para agradarles construía su propia identidad a partir esas opiniones, es decir no era ella, sino que lo que los ojos de los demás querían ver.

> opiniones que los demás tenían de mí, opiniones que, a su vez, se reflejaban en el espejo de mi **identidad**.

> La autoestima se afecta por la opinión de los demás, mientras el **amor propio** obvia a los otros, se centra exclusivamente **en sí mismo**.

3. "the lowest" como que aunque fueran **infrecuentes** las captaba de inmediato, es decir, a la más mínima opinión, sea equivocada o correcta, modificaba su identidad, por lo tanto ya estaba con la autoestima baja.

¿1), 2) o 3)<= (3) creo que no, eso sería "the slightest"? O el está mal escrito? ¿"Build" es "mejorar" o "modificar"?

Comment: Así lo veo yo: "Esto no significa, por cierto, que siempre sea simpático (no lo soy), sino que **establezco mi autoestima** mediante **las peores opiniones** ajenas sobre mí."

Comment: There is a slight issue here because it is not completely unambiguous whether the _lowest opinions_ are opinions other people have of the speaker or whether the speaker has low opinions of other people. If the former then @nopaltepec seems to me to have nailed it.

Comment: @nopaltepec Entonces, en (2) lo que mejora su autoestima es ser aceptada, esto porque los comentarios son el medio para, no son los que realmente la afectan, en cambio en (1) lo que mejoraría su autoestima sería el aceptarse o no tomarse en serio esos comentarios. Entonces build es 'construir' pero en el sentido de 'modificarse'?

Comment: Sin más contexto, no podría decir qué quiso decir quien profirió la cita original (y, por ende, no entiendo realmente tus interpretaciones o en qué las basaste). Pero lo que sí te puedo decir es que lo más idiomático en inglés es "*to build one's self-esteem [self-worth]*". A mí como nativo me da la impresión de que la autoestima es algo que se crea/se adquiere en vez de ser algo innato que se modifique o se mejore.

Comment: @mdewey It'd be a good question to ask in EEL, but I'm pretty sure there is no possible confusion: opinion of others = others' opinions; speaker having low opinions _of_ others shlould be **about** others.

Comment: Reminder: this is not a translation site.

Answer (score 0):

> "Con esto no quiero decir, por cierto, que siempre sea una persona agradable (no lo soy), sino que son **las críticas de los demás** las que **fortalecen mi propia autoestima**."

La mejor traducción que puedo ofrecer sin conocer el contexto en el que se dijo la frase.

Answer (score 0):

> “This doesn’t mean, incidentally, that I’m always likeable (I’m not) but that I **build my own self-worth** through the **lowest opinions** of others.”

La manera en la que interpreto podría ponerse como:

> Por otro lado, eso no significa que sea siempre simpático ante los demás (no lo soy), sino que **construyo mi propia autoestima** en oposición, o a pesar, de **las criticas y el menosprecio** ajeno